# How to switch a class depending on day

Tags: c#

I have a page that goes through a list of tasks (case) but I want the list to change depending what day it is,

ie. on a Saturday only do half the tasks and on a Sunday do them all.

the code I have at the moment does them all but I cant find a way to split them by day.

```
        switch (_stage)
        {
            case WizardStages.CHECK_FLIGHT_DETAILS:
                set_stepsListView("Check flight details");
                dialogueLabel.Text = "Please check all flight details";
                dialogueHelpLabel.Text = "Logsheets will be printed in the next step.";
                okayButton.Visible = true;
                noButton.Visible = false;
                yesButton.Visible = false;
                break;

            case WizardStages.PRINT_LOGSHEETS:
                set_stepsListView("Print logsheets");
                dialogueLabel.Text = "Click okay to print today's logsheets.";
                dialogueHelpLabel.Text = "Please be patient.";
                yesButton.Visible = false;
                noButton.Visible = false;
                break;
```

Can anyone throw me some ideas of where to start.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    ...
}
```

or alternatively:

```
switch (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
{
    case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
        //...
        break;
    case DayOfWeek.Monday:
        //...
        break;
    default:
        //...
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first method.

Answer (score 0):

`System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek` provides something to be able to put in a conditional.

I would decide what day it is programatically before the above switch() as I think it will result in less line.